# How secure is it to open my ssh port on my server if it uses public private key encryption?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, security, encryption

I have multiple Linux servers and would like to be able to access them from the outside using my public IP address, these servers are secured with public private key encryption and can not be authenticated with a password. Is it ok to open private port 22 to some random obscure public port or does this cause to much of a security issue.

Comment: Why change the port at all?  Provided the certificate uses an appropriate key size, it's impossible to access the account through a brute force attack, an attacker would have to run into a SHA-2 collision to access the account.  Using another port DOES NOT increase your security, it would take an attacker seconds to determine the port you used, it does nothing to increase your security.  **If you want to increase security, put everything behind a VPN, and use certificate based authentication to SSH into the machine.**  Any key smaller than 4096 is not future proof.

Comment: Not _any_ any key; only any RSA key. EC keys (the usually more recommended type) are measured differently and their minimum length is around 128 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Public key authentication for SSH, is fairly secure as long as you use a [good key algorithm and key size](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/keygen#:%7E:text=SSH%20supports%20several%20public%20key,RSA%3B%204096%20bits%20is%20better.). You can go further by using a complex password to secure the key.

From this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200792/is-ssh-with-public-key-authentication-no-passwords-secure-enough):

> The only remaining attack would be a man-in-the-middle attack You can
> copy over the host key from the server to your client, just like you
> copied a key to make public key authentication possible. This will
> completely mitigate man-in-the-middle attacks and the client will warn
> you if an attempt is detected.

As long as these mitigating factors are met, you should be fairly safe in exposing SSH to the internet.